# Signing Blackberry10 application from my developer's key

Tags: code-signing, blackberry-10

I hired a developer to develop a BB10 application for me. Now he has provided me a bar file signed with his own signing keys. Can I submit this application to App World using my account? Or I need to ask for the code and again sign the application. What is the criteria we need to match?

Thanks a bunch,
Apurv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if BlackBerry World checks keys assigned to developers against vendor accounts, I doubt that they do. However, if you submit an app signed with a particular key set, you will only be able to upgrade that application with a BAR file signed by the same key set. Does your contract include the developer providing you with source code? If you do an upgrade will you be using the same developer? The answers to these questions should help you decide.

Comment: Developer will not provide me source codes for the application and he only will be providing all future updates to the application. I guess I can directly upload the signed bar file I have received.

Comment: Sounds right. You can always run the question buy BlackBerry World support, but they seem to be very busy approving applications right now.

Comment: Yes, I have asked the same in support forums 4 days back, unfortunately no response so far. Thanks for the help.